I can't establish connection between db container and my backend, I am using flask with poney orm
I think that everything should be working just as expected but I get this eror:

The database object is not bound with a provider yet

I don't know where the issue is coming from, I attached the full error message this my first time using flask and ponyorm I have no idea how it works I checked the documentation even tried to get help form both GPT and Gemini obviously it didn't work so I had to get some help from the experts in order to grasp how to deal with these kind of issues in the futer
Attaching to api, client, db
db      | 2024-05-11 22:57:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.2.0-1.el8 started.
db      | 2024-05-11 22:57:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db      | 2024-05-11 22:57:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.2.0-1.el8 started.
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
client  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
db      | 2024-05-11 22:57:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db      | 2024-05-11T22:57:57.694717Z 0 [System] [MY-015017] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - start.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:57:57.697447Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:57:57.697680Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) initializing of server in progress as process 79
db      | 2024-05-11T22:57:57.728117Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
client  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
client  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.5
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
client  | 2024/05/11 22:57:57 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
db      | 2024-05-11T22:57:59.383721Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:02.234827Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:07.845526Z 0 [System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:07.987511Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.272775Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.274326Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) starting as process 123
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.293825Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.566513Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.945942Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.945990Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.       
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.951702Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.972412Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.972500Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:08.975168Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
db      | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
db      | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db      | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db      | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
db      | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
db      | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db      | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:12+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database saley_stock
db      |
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:12+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:12.374464Z 11 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.2.0).
api     |  (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"), retrying in 3 seconds (1/5)
api     |  (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"), retrying in 3 seconds (2/5)
api     |  (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"), retrying in 3 seconds (3/5)
api     |  (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"), retrying in 3 seconds (4/5)
api     |  (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"), retrying in 3 seconds (5/5)
api     | Traceback (most recent call last):
api     |   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
api     |     sys.exit(run())
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
api     |     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]", prog=prog).run()
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run
api     |     super().run()
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
api     |     Arbiter(self).run()
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 58, in __init__
api     |     self.setup(app)
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 118, in setup
api     |     self.app.wsgi()
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
api     |     self.callable = self.load()
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
api     |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
api     |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
api     |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
api     |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
api     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
api     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
api     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
api     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
api     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
api     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
api     |   File "/api/Backend/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
api     |     from .User.userController import UserController
api     |   File "/api/Backend/User/userController.py", line 2, in <module>
api     |     from ..Entity.Models import UserModel
api     |   File "/api/Backend/Entity/Models.py", line 82, in <module>
api     |     db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 958, in generate_mapping
api     |     if provider is None: throw(MappingError, 'Database object is not bound with a provider yet')
api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 99, in throw
api     |     raise exc
api     | pony.orm.core.MappingError: Database object is not bound with a provider yet
api exited with code 1
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.113974Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.2.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.118749Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
db      |
db      | 2024-05-11 22:58:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db      |
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.392748Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.630978Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.632333Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) starting as process 1
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.641101Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:14.798733Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:15.088586Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:15.088635Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.       
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:15.094111Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:15.122227Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db      | 2024-05-11T22:58:15.122314Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

my docker-compose file

version: "3.7"

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - stock-network
    environment:
      JWT_SECRET: top_secret_5%!1
      JWT_HASH: HS512
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 33060  # Standard MySQL port (adjust if needed)
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: mysqlrootpassword
      DB_NAME: db_name

  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - stock-network

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf # Mount custom config
      - my-db-data:/var/lib/mysql         # Named volume for MySQL data
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : mysqlrootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
    networks:
      - stock-network

networks:
  stock-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  my-db-data:

my config file

import os
from flask import jsonify
import jwt


class Config:
    db_host = os.environ.get('DB_HOST')
    db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    db_user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
    db_pass = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
    db_port = os.environ.get('DB_PORT')
    jwt_secret = os.environ.get('JWT_SECRET')
    jwt_hash = os.environ.get('JWT_HASH')


db connection function

from pony.orm import *
from ..Config.index import Config
import time


db = Database()

MAX_RETRIES = 5
RETRY_DELAY = 3  # Seconds
def connect_to_db():
    for i in range(MAX_RETRIES):
        try:
            db.bind(provider='mysql', host=Config.db_host, user='Conf.db_user', passwd=Config.db_pass, db=Config.db_name)
            print("Database connection successful!")
            return
        except OperationalError as e :
            print(f" {e}, retrying in {RETRY_DELAY} seconds ({i+1}/{MAX_RETRIES})")
            time.sleep(RETRY_DELAY)

    raise Exception("Unable to connect to the database after multiple attempts")



Where your comment on DB_PORT says "standard MySQL port", the standard port number is 3306, not 33060.  It's a little hard to tell what's wrong in the backtrace (can you fix the formatting?) but does correcting the port number help?

i already tried to change the port but still didn't succeed, i think the issue is related to docker, somehow the api container cannot establish connection to root@db on port 3306, i still have no idea how to fix that

The error messge means that mysql is either not running or on listening on a diferent port, or something else blocks your connection.

Thanks for fixing the error formatting.  Notice the continued db initialization messages after your application has failed: the application is starting up before the database is fully ready, which also can lead to a "connection refused" error.  depends_on: on its own isn't quite enough, but see Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y.

@DavidMaze thank you so much, the issue has been resolved i had to  add restart: on-failure  to my api container in order to establish the connection once initialized from db, i really appreciate that issue drove me crazy the past three days before posting it here
